# Insert a date, Highlight/move a row when date is added and highlight in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help with these Google Apps Script questions? I've never used scripts before, but I think they could solve my issues...

1. How do I most easily insert the current date?
2. Is there a way to highlight a row when the current date is added, and then move that row to the bottom of the current rows?
3. Is there a way to highlight a name field when it is a duplicate in another sheet?
4. Is there a way to highlight a row when it is highlighted in another sheet?

I would like to develop a spreadsheet to track the progress of magazine advertisers. I need to track when we receive an advertiser's information and when the ads are proofed out. (Lots of dates to insert!) Then when the ad is approved, I need to highlight that row and move it to the bottom of the other rows. (The number of current rows will be constantly changing.) Then once I receive the layout, I need to know what ads we have and of those, which are approved.

I hope someone can help me out with these questions--thank you in advance!!
Cortny!

Comment: Everything you ask is quite easily doable, I suggest you begin with getting (a bit) familiar with google script language and syntax and try step by step to get what you want. If you meet some specific issue then you'll be welcome back here.

Answer (score 0):

A few places to start at regarding Events, Triggers and Spreadsheet handling:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

I have scripts that upon editing a row record in a particular column of that row the time it was edited and in another column the username (email address) of the user editing. This script was originally in a couple of different libraries and I tried to paste the relevant portions into a single script and generalize it to the extent possible. I have not tested as it appears here -- I hope I copied everything:
https://script.google.com/d/1qVLXiKZA8SAgOoW2BAcOCtQ2bXeCNz6oRed8bN9YOOPpvdI0HzAdxeC0/edit?usp=sharing

Since this script also accesses the user's email address it must be explicitly authorized by each user before it works properly. It is for this reason that the main functions is called `onEditDelegate()` that must be added manually to the onEdit trigger instead of being called `onEdit()`. If you don't need the username, you can remove that part and it will be easier to install the script.

You can also extend this script so that when all the necessary info is entered the script copies the content of the row, deletes it from the spreadsheet and pastes it at the bottom of the sheet.

Similarly the other points you mentioned can be achieved using triggers/events.

Good luck!